# selecting strings containing at least one string as substring

Tags: python, string, for-loop, list-comprehension, string-matching

I have a list of terms:

```
terms = [
     'mani factor',
     'manner',
     'manufactur',
     'manufactur distribut',
     'manufactur facil',
     'manufactur oper',
     'manufactur process',
     'march',
     'margin',
     'market advers',
     'market condit',
     'market disrupt',
     'market price',
     'market product',
     'market result',
     'market risk',
     'market sale',
     'market share',
     'market valu',
     'materi advers',
     'materi advers affect',
     'materi advers effect',
     'materi advers impact',
     'materi affect',
     'materi impact'
]
```

and another set of terms b:

```
b = set(['risk','factor','effect','affect','impact'])
```

I want to find terms that contain at least one of the terms in b. I tried the following:

```
for t in b:
    for term in terms:
        if t in term:
            a.extend(term)
```

It leads to this output:

```
'a', 'n', 'i', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'c', 't', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'o', 'm', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'c', 't', 'o', 'r', 'f', 'a', 'c', 't', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't', 'f', 'a', 'c', 't', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'c', 'a', 'u', 's', 'f', 'a', 'c', 't', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'n', 't', 'r', 'o
```

Comment: `a.extend(term)` => `a.append(term)`

Comment: or `a = [term for t in b for term in terms if t in term]`

Comment: Thank you. This worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `append` instead of `extend` -- google the difference :-)

A nice pythonic solution is this double list-comprehension with a conditional:

```
[t for w in b for t in terms if w in t]
```

Output:

```
[
 'materi advers effect',
 'mani factor',
 'materi advers impact',
 'materi impact',
 'materi advers affect',
 'materi affect',
 'market risk'
]
```

Does that get you what you're after?